# How a "disable animations" button should look like?

Tags: buttons, icons, accessibility

As it I've been asked to add a button to disable animation on my website, according to the WCAG animation criterion (https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/animation-from-interactions.html).

The main issue I'm facing is: how should it looks? Is there an icon to represent it explicitely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pause icon is the standard way to do this, positioned close to the animated element. It would be a good practice (if the design allows) to then have a popup that says "do you want to stop all animations on the site?" and then store the answer in a cookie.

For site wide animations another option is having an "accessibility settings" screen as part of the site to toggle it on and off. That way you can have a button that explicitly says "turn off animations" which is better for people who might have trouble understanding iconography (i.e. people with autism sometimes struggle with "abstraction" of imagery and struggle to get the meaning from an icon, although a pause button is probably OK).

### prefers-reduced-motion

You should also use the CSS selector [`prefers-reduced-motion`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion).

That way you can switch animations off automatically for users who have set their OS settings to "reduced motion".

Comment: I didn't know about `prefers-reduced-motion`. Many thanks for this complete yet concise answer.